# Connect python server to internet

Tags: python-3.x, server, network-programming

I am trying to make a python server and access it via browser with any internet connection from anywhere in the world. Currently I have the following code that I got off youtube tutorials:

```
import socket
from _thread import *

host=''
port=5555
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print("Waiting for a connection")

def threadedClient(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

    storeStr = 'Server Output:'

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        for x in reply:
            if x=='\n':
                conn.sendall(str.encode(storeStr))
                storeStr = 'Server Output:'
            else:
                storeStr=storeStr+reply
                print(storeStr)


    conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to:'+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threadedClient,(conn,))
```

Using this code, I am able to connect to and interact with the server via command prompt. However, trying to connect via a browser results in:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.56:5555
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8


Unhandled exception in thread started by <function threadedClient at 
0x0000027B86E0C2F0>
```

I have tried changing the strings being sent to more HTTP like strings such as "POST / HTTP/1.1" or "Test" but this does not change anything.

Additionally, I have set up port forwarding for my laptop on my router and was wondering if further action needs to be taken for the WAN to work. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly do you "connect [...] via command prompt"? To connect using a web browser, you'll need to implement `http` on your server (or, at the very least, a subset of it).

Comment: "I have set up port forwarding for my laptop on my router and was wondering if further action needs to be taken for the WAN to work" Please keep security in mind here. Any device visible on the Internet is a target.

Comment: @Aimery Via command prompt, I connect via telnet. I will look into implementing HTTP protocols. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Also, would it be a temporary solution for the security issue if I used a spare laptop with no important information on it? Or do I really need to study up on network security? Thanks for the help!

Comment: A spare laptop is good because you can wipe and reinstall if you have any doubts. I'd still recommend studying the basics of network security (IMHO `iptables` and `fail2ban` are good starters on Linux).

Comment: I see. Do these work on Windows as well? On an unrelated note, is Linux very popular for python projects? I had the impression that only a minority of people use it but it keeps coming up in forums like this...

Comment: No, they don't. You can probably use Window's default firewall instead. Linux is pretty popular for web servers, and more generally among computer enthusiasts (which you're likely to encounter on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), which you use to connect to your Python server, is a (rather basic) text-oriented protocol. Essentially, it sends ASCII data.

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which your web browser uses, is a hypertext protocol. Thus, it may send data that your server is unable to interpret (or misinterprets). If you want to access your server from a web browser, you will need to implement the `http`protocol (or at least a subset of it).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now have a HTTP file server, again taken from a youtube tutorial. Below is the code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=='/':
            self.path='/index.html'
        try:
            file_to_open=open(self.path[1:]).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open='file not found'
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open,'utf-8'))

httpd=HTTPServer(('192.168.1.56',8081),Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I am assuming the lack of the socket library is because the sockets are handled by the HTTPServer library. But I'm still not sure how to connect this to the WAN. I have done the port-forwarding configuration necessary on my router but the port is still closed when I checked with yougetsignal.com. For port-forwarding, I have the IP 192.168.1.56 forwarded to port 8081 using TCP. I have a manually assigned IP for the laptop which should not overlap with any other device on the network since the IP was originally obtained via DHCP. Is there something else I have to do to the code? Or perhaps is there a way to use sockets with HTTPServer to achieve the result as there doesn't seem to be much documentation for the http.server library...

Comment: Please don't ask further questions in your answer, ask a new question instead.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you!